Nginx can not find static files in my docker instance
Hi I have a Django application that I'm preparing for deployment on a local network using docker. My Nginx proxy is unable to find the static files
here is my docker-compose-deploy.yaml file:
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./inventory/static:/vol/web/static
      - ./qr_codes:/vol/web/qr_codes
  
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - app

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: Inventory
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: jacob@me.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 123456
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050

volumes:
  static:
  postgres_data:

here is my DockerFile for my Django app:
# Use the official Python image from the Docker Hub
FROM python:3.8-alpine

# Set environment variables
ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp

# Create and set permissions for directories
RUN mkdir -p /app/vol/web/static /app/vol/web/qr_codes
RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /app/vol
RUN chmod -R 755 /app/vol

# Copy project files
COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

# Set the user to 'user'
USER user

# Command to run the application
CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]

My Docker file for Nginx proxy:
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.19-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

USER root
RUN mkdir -p /vol/static 
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/static

USER nginx

My default.conf file for Nginx:
server{
    listen 8080;

    location /static {
        alias /static/;
    }

    location /{
        uwsgi_pass app:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}

In my settings.py file
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/qr_codes/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'vol/web/static'
STATIC_MEDIA = 'vol/web/qr_codes'

I get this error in my docker terminal:
proxy-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2024:14:37:45 +0000] "GET /static/static/vendor/jsqr/dist/jsQR.js HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/inventory/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"


GET /static/static/ It seems like you are trying to access the static folder inside the  static directory  in your code somewhere. Are you perhaps adding the static/ prefix in your {% static %} tags?

No I'm not the same error pops up for the Django admin panel

@Victor Here is the error for the admin panel proxy-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2024:15:16:34 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/login/?next=/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

Please show us your entrypoint.sh. You would want to run the command python manage.py collectstatic at some point in time and I do not see that happening in provided code.

The Compose file mounts a volume named static into the Nginx container, but I don't see what would ever copy files into it (the same volume isn't mounted anywhere else, for example).  Can you set up Django's static file server, run collectstatic in your Dockerfile, and remove both the Nginx proxy and the mounts for static files entirely?

This is my entrypoint.sh  file
`#!/bin/sh
set -e
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
uwsgi --socket :8000 --master --enable-threads --module mysite.wsgi
Wait for the database to be ready
./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- echo "Database is up"
Run migrations and collect static files
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
Start the application
uwsgi --socket :8000 --master --enable-threads --module mysite.wsgi`

@DavidMaze I will give it a try
